# XULRunner Error: couldn't parse application.ini.

Tags: installation, xulrunner

I have downloaded XULRunner from http://releases.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/xulrunner/releases/7.0/runtimes/xulrunner-7.0.en-US.win32.zip

Unpacked this zip into folder, but when I am issuing a command

xulrunner --register-global

I am getting a message couldn't parse application.ini

I really have no application.ini file because it was no one in zip file.

So, how to install XULRunner correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Support for "registering" XULRunner has been removed in XULRunner 5.0: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=642795 (it actually wasn't exactly useful anyway). So by unpacking XULRunner you already installed it. Now you can go find or create a XULRunner application and run it with `xulrunner.exe --app path\to\app\application.ini`.