# Eclipse+Vaadin: Could not start XULRunner (version 1.9 or higher required)

Tags: eclipse, plugins, vaadin, xulrunner

When I am trying to open java file with Vaadin Editor, I am getting the following error:

```
Could not start XULRunner (version 1.9 or higher required)
```

OS: Windows 7 Prof x64
Eclipse: Indigo
XULRunner: 6.0, it is just unpacked into some folder, not installed; PATH added.

So, how to either install XULRunner for Eclipse Vaadin plugin, or how to tell Vaadin plugin where XULRunner is located?

P.S. I have tried to install xulrunner 1.9 and it din't help. So the problem persists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This plugin seems to assume a system-wide installation of XULRunner. As mentioned in [XULRunner Error: couldn't parse application.ini.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7567581/xulrunner-error-couldnt-parse-application-ini), this is no longer supported starting with XULRunner 5.0 but you could [pass in a XULRunner path explicitly](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#specifyxulrunner). This is only one part of the problem however, chances are that newer XULRunner versions simply won't work. You might actually have to download the ancient XULRunner 1.9.0 instead of XULRunner 6.0.