# RCP with SWT.Browser and XULRunner

Tags: swt, rcp, xulrunner

I'm developing an RCP application (Windows) with SWT.Browser (*SWT.MOZILLA*):

```
Browser browser = new Browser(parent, SWT.MOZILLA);
```

It's working fine with the old XULRunner 3.6.23 and the installation described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XULRunner_1.8.0.1_Release_Notes#Installing_XULRunner):

```
xulrunner.exe --register-global
```

I want to use the new XULRunner 8.x, but as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7567581/xulrunner-error-couldnt-parse-application-ini/7567781#7567781) the *old* way to install XULRunner was removed.

So I added the XULRunner-Path programmatically:

```
System.setProperty("org.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath", "Path\\To\\xulrunner_8.x");
```

But when I start my application, I'll get the following error

```
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: XPCOM error -2147467261
```

So what's the preferred way to embed XULRunner 8.x with an RCP application and avoiding this error?

Comment: I don't think SWT.Browser supports XULRunner versions newer than 1.9.2 (corresponding to Firefox 3.6): http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#browserlinux

Comment: @WladimirPalant: You are right. I overlooked this information @eclipse.org/swt/faq.php. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of [Eclipse 3.8 / 4.2 M6](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops4/S-4.2M6-201203151300/eclipse-news-M6.html#XULRunner) the `org.eclipse.swt.browser` now supports embedding XULRunner 10.0.x, but you must ship a XULRunner 10 runtime and explicitly point at it as described in the [FAQ](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#specifyxulrunner):

```
...    
    System.setProperty("org.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath", "path\to\xulrunner_10"); 
...
```

The XULRunner 10 runtime can be downloaded from [ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/xulrunner/releases/10.0/runtimes/](http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/xulrunner/releases/10.0/runtimes)

### JavaXPCOM

Mozilla is not maintaining JavaXPCOM anymore, but as [Grant Gayed says](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=327696#c11):

> The Browser does not require JavaXPCOM in order for it to work, it just exposes
>   it to apps that want to use it themselves through its getWebBrowser() method.

### Linux

XULRunner 10 will currently not run under Linux because of [Mozilla bug 720682](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=720682).

Answer (score 2):

For Windows you can also use the Internet-Explorer as browser until eclipse supports xulrunner correctly (will be in a 4.3.x version).

### For IE:

just specify

```
    -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=ie,mozilla
```

at the `eclipse.ini`.

You can read more about it [here](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#browserspecifydefault).

Answer (score 0):

I am running on windows7(64 bit) and have new xulrunner vresion:31.0.0 ([http://wiki.mozilla-x86-64.com/Download][1])

But when i try to give a path it given me error
System.setProperty("org.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath", "path\to\xulrunner_31\");

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.MessagingInterface.processCommandResult(MessagingInterface.java:342)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.MessagingInterface.syncSend(MessagingInterface.java:329)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.SWTNativeInterface.syncSend_(SWTNativeInterface.java:392)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.NativeInterface.syncSend(NativeInterface.java:104)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.Message.syncSend(Message.java:64)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.CommandMessage.syncExec(CommandMessage.java:55)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.SWTNativeComponent.runSync(SWTNativeComponent.java:201)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.SWTNativeComponent.createNativePeer(SWTNativeComponent.java:1009)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.SWTNativeComponent.access$17(SWTNativeComponent.java:989)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.SWTNativeComponent$12.run(SWTNativeComponent.java:882)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:312)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:738)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:699)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.SWTNativeComponent$CMN_createControl.run(SWTNativeComponent.java:663)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.CommandMessage.runCommand(CommandMessage.java:61)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.NativeInterface.runMessageCommand(NativeInterface.java:172)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.SWTNativeInterface.runMessageCommand(SWTNativeInterface.java:1429)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.MessagingInterface.runMessage(MessagingInterface.java:121)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.MessagingInterface.processReceivedMessages(MessagingInterface.java:106)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.MessagingInterface.access$2(MessagingInterface.java:94)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.MessagingInterface$2$2.run(MessagingInterface.java:442)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.SWTNativeInterface$OutProcess.runNativeSide(SWTNativeInterface.java:1352)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.SWTNativeInterface.main_(SWTNativeInterface.java:1461)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.NativeInterface.main(NativeInterface.java:224)
Caused by: org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: XPCOM error 0x80004005
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla.initXULRunner(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla.create(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.components.core.NativeWebBrowser.createControl(NativeWebBrowser.java:431)
    ... 19 more
```

Without that it showing IE 9.0 or with another xulunner which i not confirm from where get this is working fine but showing firefox version 5.0. Any idea how i can update with latest firefox version.

Comment: According to https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=422561 the latest supported version of XULrunner is 24 (as of Eclipse 4.4 M5).

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse_4.4.2 now supports XULRunner24.0, you can try this version.