# How to integrate XML Schema view in eclipse RCP application

Tags: eclipse, view, xsd, integration, rcp

Ok so here is the deal. I have to open an xsd file trough a menu and then a view must be opened showing the structure of the xsd file but without opening an editor. I know how to open it trough the menu. What i don't know is if there is a plugin view that i can use to integrate in my rcp app to show the structure of that xsd file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use RCP with `swt.browser` running [Webkit](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#howusewebkit) or [XULRunner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7890994/rcp-with-swt-browser-and-xulrunner) to use either browser engine as a simple XML viewer.