# SWT x64 with xulrunner 3.6.28 x86

Tags: java, browser, 64-bit, swt, xulrunner

is there any way to run xulrunner 3.6.28 (x86 there is no other) with swt x64?

I cant use the newer xulrunner 10.4esr becouse i have some issues with it. The old one runs like a charm, but there is no x64 of it.

If i try loading 3.6.28 i get some weird errors:

```
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: XPCOM error 0x80004005
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla.initXULRunner(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla.create(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at GUI.TFSBrowser$1.run(TFSBrowser.java:54)
```

Any suggestions?

Kind regards 
David

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14447126/using-the-64bit-xulrunner-in-eclipse-swt-under-windows

Answer (score 0):

Try to compile your project SWT using swtx86.jar and embed a JRE 32 bits with the installation, it's work for 64 and 32 bits arch.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this question is old, but hopefully this will help someone else who stumbles across it.

With 64-bit 4.3 SWT I was able to fix this exception by using XULRunner version 1.9.2.25 runtimes. This may not be the exact solution you are (or were) looking for since it seems you were using later XULRunner versions, however the common denominator seems to be the 64-bit libraries being used.

Originally I found the download from here: https://osdn.net/projects/sfnet_runawfe/downloads/SRC%20and%20BIN%20files/extras/xulrunner-1.9.2.25-win64.zip/

However, I have also re-hosted it as [`xulrunner-1.9.2.25.en-US.win64.zip`](http://repo.thedesertmonk.com/artifactory/generic/org/mozilla/xulrunner/1.9.2.25/runtimes/xulrunner-1.9.2.25.en-US.win64.zip).

Full explanation posted in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44848877/3300205

Related post: [Creating a SWT.MOZILLA browser on Windows 64 bit and SWT 4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21378295/creating-a-swt-mozilla-browser-on-windows-64-bit-and-swt-4-3/44962070#44962070)