# Creating a SWT.MOZILLA browser on Windows 64 bit and SWT 4.3

Tags: java, swt, mozilla, xulrunner

I'm trying to create an SWT Browser widget of the SWT.MOZILLA type under windows 8 64Bit with SWT 4.3 64Bit.

According to [this](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#howusemozilla), SWT 4.3 should support 64 Bit version on XULRunner 10.x or 24.x

So, I have downloaded both the 10.x and 24.x 64 versions from [here](http://wiki.mozilla-x86-64.com/Download) and unzipped under `c:\xulrunner10` and `c:\xulrunner24` respectively.

If I start my java app pointing to xulrunner10 (using the VM argument `-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath=C:\xulrunner10`) it works, however if I try with xulrunner24 (using the VM argument `-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath=C:\xulrunner24`) I get the follwoing error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: XPCOM error 0x80004005
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla.initXULRunner(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla.create(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

I also noticed that I get the same error if pointing to unexisting directory, however the folder c:\xulrunner24 exists and contains all the files as well as xulrunner.exe.

How can I make xulrunner 24.x 64bit embeddable in my swt 4.3 app?

Comment: Have you checked this bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=327696 ?

Comment: mmm not sure it's my case since xulrunner 10 works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it!
It's an error on SWT wiki: xulrunner 24.x requires SWT 4.4.
I've installed swt-4.4M5 and now I can embed xurlrunner 24 64bit

Answer (score 1):

I realize that this question is old and already has an accepted answer, but the download location mentioned in the question is no longer valid (http://wiki.mozilla-x86-64.com/Download), and the same issue has been posted about several times.

With 64-bit 4.3 SWT I was able to fix this exception by using XULRunner version 1.9.2.25 runtimes. Originally I found the download from here: https://osdn.net/projects/sfnet_runawfe/downloads/SRC%20and%20BIN%20files/extras/xulrunner-1.9.2.25-win64.zip/

However, I have also re-hosted it as [`xulrunner-1.9.2.25.en-US.win64.zip`](http://repo.thedesertmonk.com/artifactory/generic/org/mozilla/xulrunner/1.9.2.25/runtimes/xulrunner-1.9.2.25.en-US.win64.zip).

Full explanation posted in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44848877/3300205

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this might be [Eclipse bug 411996](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=411996) (same error and stack trace).