# DJ Native Swing browser with 64 bit SWT and JVM

Tags: java, jvm, xulrunner, djnativeswing

I have created a java application embedding the native swing browser. It's running perfectly fine on 32 bit JVM on windows. I want to make it run on 64 bit JVM windows. For the same purpose, I have downloaded a 64 bit SWT jar and some xul runners which are labelled to be 64 bit. But i am getting target exception.

Exception :

```
***java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.MessagingInterface.processCommandResult(MessagingInterface.java:342)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.MessagingInterface.syncSend(MessagingInterface.java:329)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.SWTNativeInterface.syncSend_(SWTNativeInterface.java:392)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.NativeInterface.syncSend(NativeInterface.java:104)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.Message.syncSend(Message.java:64)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.CommandMessage.syncExec(CommandMessage.java:55)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.SWTNativeComponent.runSync(SWTNativeComponent.java:201)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.SWTNativeComponent.createNativePeer(SWTNativeComponent.java:1006)
    at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.SWTNativeComponent.access$17(SWTNativeComponent.java:989)....
```

The exception seems to be lengthy. So only posting a part of the same.

I know the exception is regarding the lack of required xulrunner.

But how can I solve the issue?
Please help.

Comment: Post the full exception traceback

Comment: I have posted a cut down version of the same. I heard something like 64 bit xulrunner which supports dj browser are not there and all.
I am really confused.

Comment: If I am not creating the JBrowser without a xulrunner, it is running properly. I think it is using the native IE support. But I want to get the firefox support. So that I used xulrunner. And it was working fine on 32 bit JVM.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a SWT.MOZILLA browser on Windows 64 bit and SWT 4.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21378295/creating-a-swt-mozilla-browser-on-windows-64-bit-and-swt-4-3)