# XULRunner with swt x64 under Windows

Tags: 64-bit, swt, mozilla, xulrunner

I try using Mozilla as the Browser's underlying renderer in Eclipse Neon, but i get the error as following, same problem with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21378295/creating-a-swt-mozilla-browser-on-windows-64-bit-and-swt-4-3/41507085?noredirect=1#comment70219701_41507085).

```
Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: XPCOM error 0x80004005
at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla.error(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla.initXULRunner(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla.create(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

As I understand answer of above question I need 64 version XULRunner for Windows but 64 bit XULRunner download link (http://wiki.mozilla-x86-64.com/Download) is forbidden and there is no available site for XULRunner 64 bit version.

Is there any way to run XULRunner with swt x64?

Any suggestion?
Thanks