# XPCOM error in maven SWT project on windows 10 64 bit

Tags: java, maven, swt, xulrunner

I am trying to run simplest example of SWT browser with MOZILLA as default renderer. and getting this error

```
--- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) @ SwtBrowser ---
Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: XPCOM error 0x80004005
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla.initXULRunner(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla.create(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at dev.nazm.swt.Mozilla.main(Mozilla.java:57)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I googled this problem and got these answers, but none of these are any help

1. [Creating a SWT.MOZILLA browser on Windows 64 bit and SWT 4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21378295/creating-a-swt-mozilla-browser-on-windows-64-bit-and-swt-4-3)
2. [How to make SWT Browser control use mozilla instead of IE on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2086734/how-to-make-swt-browser-control-use-mozilla-instead-of-ie-on-windows)
3. [Cannot run due to XPCOM error 0x80004005 #48](https://github.com/gnosygnu/xowa/issues/48)
4. [The SWT FAQ](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#howusemozilla)

And some other links on eclipse support. But nothing helped me

This is my `pom.xml`

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>dev.nazm</groupId>
    <artifactId>SwtBrowser</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>SwtBrowser</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven-eclipse-repo</id>
            <url>http://maven-eclipse.github.io/maven</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>${swtGroup}</groupId>
            <artifactId>${swtArtifact}</artifactId>
            <version>${swtVersion}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>naz.dev</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx.embed.swt</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.0-Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-invoker</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency> 

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jogamp.gluegen</groupId>
            <artifactId>gluegen-rt-main</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jogamp.jogl/jogl-all-main -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jogamp.jogl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jogl-all-main</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>osgi.core</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.core/org.eclipse.core.runtime -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.core.runtime</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>mac</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <name>Mac OS X</name>
                    <arch>x86_64</arch>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.6.0</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>exec</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>java</executable>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>-XstartOnFirstThread</argument>
                                <argument>-classpath</argument>
                                <classpath/>
                                <argument>dev.nazm.browser.SwtBrowser</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
            <properties>
                <swtGroup>org.eclipse.swt</swtGroup>
                <swtArtifact>org.eclipse.swt.cocoa.macosx.x86_64</swtArtifact>
                <swtVersion>4.4</swtVersion>                
            </properties>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>windows10_64</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <name>windows 10</name>
                    <family>Windows</family>
                    <arch>amd64</arch>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <swtGroup>org.eclipse.swt</swtGroup>
                <swtArtifact>org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64</swtArtifact>
                <swtVersion>4.4</swtVersion>
            </properties>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>windows32</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <family>Windows</family>
                    <arch>x86</arch>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <swtGroup>org.eclipse.swt</swtGroup>
                <swtArtifact>org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86</swtArtifact>
                <swtVersion>4.4</swtVersion>
                <!--<classifier>debug</classifier>-->
            </properties>
        </profile>       
    </profiles>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- specify UTF-8, ISO-8859-1 or any other file encoding -->
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>dev.nazm.browser.SwtBrowser</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

I have downloaded xulrunner 24.0 and extracted it to C:\Program Files\xulrunner24 .

This is my main class

```
public class SwtBrowser {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String path = "C:\\Program Files\\xulrunner24";
        System.getProperties().setProperty("org.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath",path);
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
        Browser browser = new Browser(shell, SWT.MOZILLA);
        browser.setUrl("https://chromium.github.io/octane/");
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

This is my java version

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)`
```

I am trying this on Windows 10 amd64 environment. 
I have installed Mozilla FirefoxESR 24.0 on my computer.
I have installed VisualC++ Redistributable also

Now my questions are ?

1. Does Firefox version installed on my PC needs to meet version of xulrunner.
2. As SWT FAQ says requirements  of Windows (x86_64):

   > Any XULRunner release with version 1.9.2.x - 3.6.x, 10.x or 24.x, and
   >   the Visual C++ 2010 runtime must be installed

   Does OS architecture matters for xulrunner?
3. I have installed eclipse neon 3, and tried creating a project and adding runtime arguments in .ini file. But still got the same issue. So final question is how to run it in a maven project on a Windows 64 bit platform.

Answer (score 0):

With 64-bit 4.3 SWT (and 4.4 - I've only tested those two) I was able to run your code by using XULRunner version 1.9.2.25 runtime.

I also had to update your `pom.xml` to pull 64-bit SWT (`org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64` instead of `org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86`) because of the 64-bit JVM (1.8.0_131 in my case).

Originally I found the xulrunner download from here: https://osdn.net/projects/sfnet_runawfe/downloads/SRC%20and%20BIN%20files/extras/xulrunner-1.9.2.25-win64.zip/

However, I have also re-hosted it as [`xulrunner-1.9.2.25.en-US.win64.zip`](http://repo.thedesertmonk.com/artifactory/generic/org/mozilla/xulrunner/1.9.2.25/runtimes/xulrunner-1.9.2.25.en-US.win64.zip) in my repository.

In regards to doing this in a Maven project, I'm not sure. You could simply package it with your application in a `lib` directory. If it would help to have the xulrunner runtime packaged and put in a Maven repository I can host it that was as well (our you can host it yourself on a repo that you own).

Let me know if this doesn't work and I'll be happy to take another look.