# Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: XPCOM error 0x80004005 in swt.mozilla

Tags: java, eclipse, browser, swt, mozilla

> following my SWT code which use  Mozilla browser but it gives me an error xpcomm error 0x80004005.

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.io.File;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FormAttachment;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FormData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FormLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.ui.internal.dnd.SwtUtil;

public class Newbrowser {
    public static void main(String a[]) {
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        /* Composite controls = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE); */
        shell.setText("Browser");
        String pathToXulrunner = "C://Program Files (x86)/Mozilla XULRunner/";

        System.setProperty("org.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath", pathToXulrunner);

        /*
         * System.setProperty("org.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath",
         * pathToXulrunner);
         */
        System.setProperty("org.eclipse.swt.browser.MOZ_PROFILE_PATH", new File("").getAbsolutePath());
        Browser browser = new Browser(shell, SWT.MOZILLA);
        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
        shell.open();

        FormData data = new FormData();

        data.top = new FormAttachment(0, 0);
        data.bottom = new FormAttachment(100, 0);
        data.left = new FormAttachment(0, 0);
        data.right = new FormAttachment(100, 0);
        browser.setLayoutData(data);
        browser.setUrl("www.google.com");

        // Set up the event loop.

        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                // If no more entries in the event queue
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

Please help me to solve this problem. thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of SWT and what version of XULRunner are you using? Have you seen this post: [Creating a SWT.MOZILLA browser on Windows 64 bit and SWT 4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21378295/creating-a-swt-mozilla-browser-on-windows-64-bit-and-swt-4-3)? Without a bit more detail I can't tell whether or not this is a duplicate.

Comment: Hi thanks for comment, i am using SWT 4.5.2 and Xulrunner 10.X in windows 64 bit

Comment: @avojak please help me for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the notes on using XULRunner [here](https://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php), it looks like using version 10.x is correct.

I was able to get your code running by downloading [XULRunner 10.0.4esr](http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/xulrunner/releases/10.0.4esr/sdk/). I followed the installation steps given [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18010125/3300205), as well as pointing to the `bin` directory specifically.

1. Download `xulrunner-10.0.4esr.en-US.win32.sdk.zip` [from this directory](http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/xulrunner/releases/10.0.4esr/sdk/)
2. Extract the contents and move the `xulrunner` directory to some location (I used `c:/xulrunner`, but in your case `C:/Program Files (x86)/XULRunner` should be fine too.
3. Either use the VM argument (`-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.XULRunnerPath`), or use `System.setProperty()` as you are currently. Be sure that the path that you specify points to the `bin` directory, not just the top level `xulrunner` directory.

---

Make sure you have that version of XULRunner (and specifically the SDK), and verify that the file path you are pointing to exists. Depending on where you unzip the download, you may need to replace:

```
String pathToXulrunner = "C://Program Files (x86)/Mozilla XULRunner/";
```

with:

```
String pathToXulrunner = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Mozilla XULRunner/bin";
```

I'm also running 64-bit Windows 10 with SWT 4.5.2, so we should have the same setup.

---

Edit: I just realized I was doing this with 32-bit libraries (32-bit Java and 32-bit SWT). So if you're by any chance using 32-bit libraries, this should work. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21378295/creating-a-swt-mozilla-browser-on-windows-64-bit-and-swt-4-3) you should be able to use XULRunner 24 with a 64-bit JRE, however I was not able to get this working.

---

Edit 2: For 64-bit libraries, I found the contents of the bin directory for xulrunner-1.9.2.25 here: https://osdn.net/projects/sfnet_runawfe/downloads/SRC%20and%20BIN%20files/extras/xulrunner-1.9.2.25-win64.zip/

With this downloaded, I was able to run your code. Note that this is the contents of the `bin` directory (equivalent to downloading the runtimes instead of the SDK), so you can exclude the `bin` from your file path for `pathToXulrunner`.

I can't right this minute, but I'll host this somewhere else and update the post later.

---

Edit 3: I've re-hosted this as [`xulrunner-1.9.2.25.en-US.win64.zip`](http://repo.thedesertmonk.com/artifactory/generic/org/mozilla/xulrunner/1.9.2.25/runtimes/xulrunner-1.9.2.25.en-US.win64.zip)

Comment: yes it is working with 32-bit libraries (32-bit Java and 32-bit SWT) ,but what about 64 bit libraries? i was  still not able to get this on 64 bit libraries.

Comment: @Bhavikpatel See my second edit - I found the contents of the `bin` directory for a win64 version of xulrunner and was able to run your code.

Comment: @Bhavikpatel Was this able to help at all?