# Unable to open Eclipse on windows7. Could not load SWT library. Reasons:

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am newbie on `Android` as well as on `Phone gap`. I am using `Windows 7` based machine.

I am trying to develop application on `Phone gap for android`.

I had installed Android `ADT Bundle` and then `Phone gap Plugins in Eclipse`.

And now i am trying to create an Application, But it is giving me and `Error`.

```
(Build 1.5.0.25458) [ERROR] Unabled to create browser control:Firefox
No more handles (java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not load SWT library. Reasons: 
    no swt-xulrunner-win32-4234 in java.library.path
    no swt-xulrunner-win32 in java.library.path
    Can't load library: C:\Users\tom\.swt\lib\win32\x86_64\swt-xulrunner-win32-4234.dll
    Can't load library: C:\Users\tom\.swt\lib\win32\x86_64\swt-xulrunner-win32.dll
)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14447126/using-the-64bit-xulrunner-in-eclipse-swt-under-windows

Comment: @ant: possibly duplicate but i am not getting solution for me. from that question. :(